# Cannot add images to my web application

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hello i am trying to add images to my web application on google app engine
using

```
<img src=''>
```

My html page in this directory

```
/templates/control-panel/index.html
```

and my app.yaml file

```
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /templates/control-panel/assets/img
  static_dir: img
- url: .*
  script: main.app
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

so in my html page i've added

```
<img src='/img/find_person.png'>
```

and the pic didn't load

can any one help ?

Comment: Well, that image URL doesn't match the path in app.yaml.

Comment: ok what can i write in app.yaml and index.html

Comment: If you need to match `/img`, then your URL entry should start with `/img`.

Comment: i want to match /templates/control-panel/assets/img    to /img or any directory   but the html file in this directory   /templates/control-panel/index.html

Comment: I don't understand that comment. I also don't understand why you've put your assets inside the templates directory: assets are not templates.

Comment: Thank you the problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you misunderstood how static dir handlers work (you have things backwards) The **url** is the **published location** of the item (i.e. how you reference it in your html) while **static_dir** is where it actually exists in your app's dir hierarchy.

From your description this seems to be what you want:

```
- url: /img
  static_dir: templates/control-panel/assets/img
```